# Handling responses from an outputstream

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency, client-server, stream-processing

I have an InputStream and an OutputStream to a server. I can send a bunch of JSON requests over the wire and get a stream of responses back from this server. From this, I'd like to build a wrapper that provides getters like `getFoo()` that create a request, send it, and get a response.

I'm not sure how to handle this considering I may have many clients using this single InputStream and OutputStream at a given time, and am hoping there's a good way to design this.

Here's one option I considered:

- InputStream reader constantly reads responses, and puts them in a `Map<RequestType, Response>` that stores the latest Response for each RequestType (where requestType is `getFoo`, `getBar`, etc)
- When I call `getFoo()` on my wrapper, it writes the request to OutputStream, and then sits waiting for `responseMap.get(RequestType.FOO)`, reads it, and deletes that entry in the map.

Another option:

- When I call `getFoo()` on my wrapper, it registers itself as a callback with the InputStream reader
- When the InputStream reader parses a response (e.g. the `foo` response from above) it notifies all listeners waiting for `foo` response, then clears the listeners.

Both of these seem fragile when I start thinking about concurrency. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Is it impossible to add a (synchronizedly) unique identifier for each request?
There are multiple threads/processes that might write requests to the OutputStream and read from the Map at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I can add a unique ID to requests so I can match up a response with a request. I feel confident I can match up a response to a request, just not sure how to notify the caller.

Comment: Is your server handling continuous connections, such as an IRC connection (where the responses aren't one-time like HTTP)? In that way, what is wrong with concurrency in the second option?

Comment: I was concerned about adding and removing callbacks while other clients are making calls but that shouldn't be an issue with a unique ID. I have a bit more confidence now, I'll start working on the second proposal, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an InputStream and an OutputStream to a server. I can send a
>   bunch of JSON requests over the wire and get a stream of responses
>   back from this server

Can you not just open multiple connections to the server, and hence get multiple input/output streams ? In that scenario you can assert that the component opening that connection will only get the responses meant for it, and it alone.